# Create syntactic sugar to define a variable as a class instance

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, types, syntactic-sugar

I'm trying to create my own class that acts like a regular type, like this:

```
class CustomType:
    def __init__(self, content):
        self.content = content
    def __str__(self):
        return self.content
```

This means I can do something like this:

```
a = CustomType("hi there")
print(a)  # 'hi there'
```

But the problem is that I have to use `a = CustomType("hi there")`. Is there a way I can do something  like `a = /hi there\` or a similar solution that lets me create my own syntactic sugar?

Thanks.

Comment: There would be no way for the parser to know to look for that

Comment: Nope. Not unless you wanna hack the source.

Answer (score 6):

No.  Python does not support creating new syntax.

Answer (score 3):

**Note**: I would not suggest doing this.

You can't do that because the parser wouldn't know to look for it, but if you wanted something similar, you could create a custom class that returns a new instance of `CustomType` when divided by a string:

```
class CustomSyntax:
    def __truediv__(self, value):
        return CustomType(value)
```

Then if you had an instance of that class (let's call it `c`), you could divide it by a string any time you wanted an instance of `CustomType`:

```
a = c/'hi there'
b = c/'hello world'
```

However, that's a little weird, and you'd be best off sticking to your regular constructor.